# Display Parent and child taxonomies in seperate drop downs

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display parent and child taxonomies in separate drop downs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47346/how-can-i-display-parent-and-child-taxonomies-in-separate-drop-downs)

does anyone have solution for the requirement where i have a taxonomy State which is the parent and it has a child sub-taxonomy called City, Need to display the state as a drop down, when i select the state tax i have to display the city tax in the second drop down.....kindly help me..

Answer (score 0):

[get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) does what you want.

```
<?php
$cities = get_terms( 'state', array(
    'child_of'    => 3 //ID of the state term
    //other args you want see the docs
));
var_dump($cities);
```

Not tested but it should work.
GL